# How to get InnerHTML from a HTML Document Table with HTML AgilityPack in C#?

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am programming a mobile App in Xamarin Forms(C#).

There I need some Text from a HTML Document. For this I use the HTML Agility Pack to parse the HTML Document.

So I get the HTML Node with the `id="recipe-incredients".` But now I don't know how to go on. I need the information from the table (see in picture). The table with the `class="recipe-incredients"`.

How can I navigate to the table and get the content of it in C# with the HTML Agility Pack?

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GFtT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the table in a similar way to selecting the div. Just use XPath to select the table element that has `class="recipe-incredients"`. Then you can get the contents of the table with `.OuterHtml`.

```
HtmlNode div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='recipe-incredients']");

HtmlNode table = div.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='incredients']");

String tableContent = table.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks right. But i can´t choose DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode. Do you know why i can´t choose it? I can´t understand this.. i am using HTML Agility Pack with the newest Version.Do you know how i can reach the right result with LINQ?

Comment: @Dahl93 It will be easier to help you if you could post your code.